# XAMPP + Laravel + AdminLTE

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, adminlte

Alright, so I got super excited when I found the [Admin Dash](https://github.com/evercode1/admin-dash) Laravel template which ports the entire AdminLTE template over to Laravel 5.4, including sample pages, db tables, etc., just to hit a roadblock when trying to run this on my local XAMPP Server...

I followed the instructions and:

- created a new Laravel project via `laravel new test3` in `Z:/xampp/htdocs/`
- downloaded the Admin-Dash files and pasted them into the new project folder (test3)
- ran `php artisan migration`
- ran `npm install`
- edited my `.env` file to point to the correct folder `APP_URL=http://localhost/test3`.

which resulted in this:
[image]

None of the supposedly provided sites such as `/login/` or `/register/` nor the  CSS / JS features seem to work, most likely due to the template looking for the `dist` folder in `http://localhost/dist/` while they are actually located in `Z:/xampp/htdocs/test3/public/dist`.

How can I change the folder destination in the template? Appreciate any help on that, thank you!
A2k

**EDIT**

As pointed out earlier, there is a problem with the css/js folder location. I have since located the blades for Admin/Guest/Common in `Z:\xampp\htdocs\test3\resources\views\layouts` and adjusted them as following:

eg. jQuery

```
<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>

to
<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="/test3/public/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
```

This seems to finally fix the layout issue, but when clicking on any link such as eg. `/register/` it points me to `http://localhost/register/` instead of `http://localhost/test3/register/`. It shouldnt be necessary to mess around with the master blade configuration which makes me wonder if there is a master setting for the Admin-Dash path that I am missing?

**EDIT 2**

Since the CSS/JS issue was fixed by utilizing `{{ asset }}`, the only problem left are the routes. Right now, when navigating to eg `http://localhost/test3/register/` I receive a 404 error, suggesting problems with either the APP URL or routes. Both below:

**localhost/test3/routes/web.php**

```
// Registration routes
Route::get('register', 'Auth\AuthController@showRegistrationForm')->name('register');
Route::post('register', 'Auth\AuthController@register');
```

**localhost/test3/config/app.php**

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/test4'),
```

Latest screenshot of the console:
[image]

Comment: css and js  path is not added correctly.

Comment: keep all the js and css in public folder and add from their to  you master blade

Comment: I looked at the master blades in `Z:\xampp\htdocs\test3\resources\views\layouts` but do not see any references to the `/dist/ or /js/ or /css/` folder. Some guest blades seem to point towards the `bootstrap` folder which I have adjusted but without success.

Comment: keep all our css and js in public folder now call them to that blade where you want to add. as your screen shot shows their is problem of css and js path not added correctly. so can you send me the how you are calling css and js to your blade page?

Comment: @KuldeepMishra updated the post. It seems strange to me that I have to adjust the master blades manually. Is there perhaps a setting for the path I am missing?

Comment: First remove `/test3` from `src="/test3/public/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"`.

Comment: @HirenGohel this would cause the script to look at `localhost/public/plugins/...` which is invalid...

Comment: Define it like: `{{ asset('plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js') }}` Be sure that you have `jquery-2.2.3.min.js` in `plugins/jQuery/` directory!

Comment: Have you got any errors??

Comment: @HirenGohel I defined all blade css / js references as `{{asset ''}}` which seems to have worked for all the CSS/JS errors. The remaining problem is still that the routes to pages such as `/register/` are not working. I already updated the `url` in `/config/app.php' to reflect the correct folder but no success.

Comment: The `{{asset ''}}` path is not gives you error what you said about routes problem! Anyways, what type of errors you got?? I fixed your `{{asset ''}}` problem , i think i can also help for this! :)

Comment: @HirenGohel what I mean is that after using `{{Asset}}` the css errors are gone, no problem there. The issue now is that when navigating to eg. `http://localhost/test4/register' I get an 404 error, which suggests that the routes have problems. Thanks

Comment: Can you show me your `routes` for `/register` and also show me `url` in `/config/app.php`

Comment: Define `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/test4'),` in `config/app.php` and then try. Let me know if it works!

Comment: @HirenGohel did that already without success... See the edit please.

Comment: Have you created virtual host or not??

Comment: No, if I would use a vhost I wouldnt have to go through all this of course, but since I am managing multiple project folders in my `/htdocs/` dir, I prefer to address them manually

Comment: Is `php artisan serve` is working?? And then try your `url` for `/register` Your image displayed that you are working with `vue`

Comment: Is that works??

Comment: @HirenGohel so, I started over from scratch, reinstalled the whole thing and set up a virtual host to run this from. It turns out that Admin-Dash must be installed into the `/htdocs/ ' folder and does not support any subfolders. Subfolders for each website only work when a virtual host is set up. Thanks for pointing me there~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the `/test3` from your `src="/test3/public/plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"`. Then, define `css/js` path like: `{{ asset('plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js') }}`.

Be sure that you have `jquery-2.2.3.min.js` in `plugins/jQuery/` directory!

Make changes in `config/app.php` like `url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost/test4'),`

Use project by creating `virtualhost` easily and also for implementing and redirection!

Hope this steps may fixed you problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

1) Install composer dependencies

```
composer install
```

2) An application key need to be generated with the command

```
php artisan key:generate
```

3) Open Project in a Code Editor, rename `.env.example` to `.env` and modify DB name, username, password to your environment.

4) Migrate the database along with seed

```
php artisan migrate --seed
```

**EDIT**: You could prefix 'test3' to every route like this:

```
Route::prefix('test3')->group(function () {
    //your all routes inside here
});
```

Check here for more : [route-group-prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#route-group-prefixes)

Comment: I did all that and ended up with what I described in the original post :(

Comment: Change `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),' to 
http://localhost/test3 in config/app.php

Comment: Or you colud prefix 'test3' to every route like this

Route::prefix('test3')->group(function () {
 //your all routes inside here
});

Comment: I adjusted the `url` and prefixed the routes, but both without success. There has to be a master setting for the path somewhere I am missing...

Comment: You just change back your url to localhost in both .env and config/app.php and try only route prefix. It might work.